# Different Polynomial Expansions of Natural Logarithm

Tags: logarithms, taylor-expansion

I was recently Taylor-expanding `ln` around $(1,0)$. I noticed that this polynomial will have a range of input that converges between $0$ and $2$ regardless of Taylor order. I then found an expansion that did not seem to have this issue, namely:

$\lim_{n \to +\infty} 2 \cdot \sum\limits_{i=0}^n (\frac{1}{2i + 1} \cdot {(\frac{x-1}{x+1})}^{2i + 1}) = \ln(x)$

My question is: how is this formula derived (as in created, not the derivative) from `ln`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you combine the Taylor series for $\log(1+x)$ and  $\log(1-x)$ you arrive to a well known series which is $$\log \frac{1+x}{1-x}=2  \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2i+1}}{2i + 1} $$ So now define $y=\frac {1+x}{1-x}$ that is to say $x=\frac{y-1}{y+1}$ and you end with $$\log(y)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2i + 1} (\frac{y-1}{y+1})^{2i+1}$$

Comment: I question; why was this necessary? Should this not be the direct output of the taylor algorithm? Is there a specific method to finding taylor expansions of functions that are not expanded so easily as cos or sin (like ln)? Also; what is the intuition behind this method? I understand that substitution is in place, but is it because 1-x and 1+x allow Maclaurin series?

Comment: I am not sure to answer your question in the comment. A Taylor expansion gives you a polynomial in the rhs. Then, specific changes of variable allow this kind of manipulation.

Comment: @BourgondAries This approach is necessary due to the singularity of $\log(x)$ at $x=0$. For well-behaved functions like $\sin, \cos, \exp$, it is not necessary.

Comment: $f(x) = \ln x$ is actually easily expanded: its derivatives ares $f^{(n)}(x) = (-1)^{n-1} (n-1)! x^{-n}$, so around any point $a$ its series is $$\ln x = \ln a + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k-1} \frac{(x-a)^{n}}{a^n n} $$ Of course, this could just has been easily computed by plugging in $x \mapsto x/a$ into the series for $\ln x$ centered at $1$.

Comment: @AlexR: Does this imply there a theorem stating that in order to approximate _any_ function, it _must_ be expanded from its origin?

Comment: @Hurkyl: When expanding around 6, 20 times, the resulting polynomial starts decreasing exponentially at around 4, this result appears undesired.

Comment: @BourgondAries No, certainly not. But the $\log$ having a singularity limits the radius of convergence of a Taylor series expansion to $|x_0 - 0|$ with $x_0 > 0$ the point of expansion. The desire for a globally convergent series emerges these "advanced" techniques.

Comment: @Bourgond: In fact, the series diverges whenever $|x-a| > a$, and converges whenever $|x-a| < a$ (as easily seen by the ratio test). That the radius is $a$ is because $\ln x$ is singular at $x=0$ (the only other singularity is at $\infty$). The radius of convergence of a Taylor series for an analytic function always turns out to be the distance from the center to the nearest singularity. For $\sin(x)$, the only singularity is at $\infty$, thus you always get an infinite radius of convergence, no matter where you expand it at.

Comment: Oh I think I understand now. Thanks all for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

This is outlined on the wikipedia page for [natural logs.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm)

You start with the taylor series about $x=0$ for $\log(1+x) = \sum_n \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} x^n$ for $|x|<1$.

Then, apply a [Binomial/Euler transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_transform) to get a series for $\log \frac{x}{x-1} = \sum_n \frac{1}{n} x^{-n}$.

Then, substitute $x = \frac{u}{u-1}$ to get the desired series after a shift of indices. note that it doesn't converge for all $x$ (exercise: what $x$ does it converge for?)

Comment: In the sentence mentioning the Binomial/Euler transform, is the log part of the formula supposed to be part of the equation?

Answer (score 0):

Replace $x$ by $\frac{1-x}{1+x}$ in

$$\operatorname{arctanh}(x)=-\frac12\ln\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$

we get

$$-\frac12\ln(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)^{2n+1}}{2n+1}=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\left(\frac{x-1}{1+x}\right)^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$

or

$$\ln(x)=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\left(\frac{x-1}{1+x}\right)^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$